# Fast java routine to determine if request URI is within another URL

Tags: java, url

In a class (Java8), I have a String representing an HTTP URL, e.g. `String str1="http://www.foo.com/bar"`, and another string containing a request URI e.g. `str2="/bar/wonky/wonky.html"`.

What is the fastest way in terms of code execution to determine if str2 is within the context of str1 (e.g. the context is /bar) and then construct the complete url `String result = "http://www.foo.com/bar/wonky/wonky.html"`?

Comment: Is there anything about the two strings that you can always assume? like str2 is always a path starting with a slash or str1 will always include the protocol and host?

Comment: Yes str2 will always start with /, and str1 is always protocol://host[:port]/context

Comment: `str2.startsWith(str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/')`

Comment: is the `/context` of `str1` always guaranteed to not include a slash after the root?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if there is a faster way to just use `String.indexOf()`.  Here is an approach that I think covers the example you gave ([demo](https://repl.it/KtRh/9)):

```
  public static boolean overlap(String a, String b_context) {
    //Assume the a URL starts with http:// or https://, the next / is the start of the a_context
    int root_index = a.indexOf("/", 8);
    String a_context = a.substring(root_index);
    String a_host = a.substring(0, root_index);
    return b_context.startsWith(a_context);
  }
```

Here is a function that uses the same logic but to combine the two urls if they overlap or throw an exception if they don't

```
  public static String combine(String a, String b_context) {
    //Assume the a URL starts with http:// or https://, the next / is the start of the a_context
    int root_index = a.indexOf("/", 8);
    String a_context = a.substring(root_index);
    String a_host = a.substring(0, root_index);
    if(b_context.startsWith(a_context)) {
      return a_host + b_context;
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("urls do not overlap");
    }
  }
```

And here is an example of using them

```
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    System.out.println(combine("http://google.com/search", "/search?query=Java+String+Combine"));
    System.out.println(combine("http://google.com/search", "/mail?inbox=Larry+Page"));
  }
```

Comment: `lastIndexOf('/')` would be better than `indexOf("/", 8)`. --- In the first example, what is the point of `a_host`?

Comment: Wouldn't that assume the str1 never had another `/`? indexOf("/", 8) assumes that there is always a 3rd slash.

Comment: OP said in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137040/fast-java-routine-to-determine-if-request-uri-is-within-another-url#comment79236376_46137040): *str1 is always protocol://host[:port]/context*. So according to OP, that assumption is valid. Your code would be wrong too, if that wasn't the case, because `a_context` would then contain more than just the context path.

Comment: I just tested the code with a URL that includes more than one slash (https://repl.it/KtRh/10) so I know the approach of `indexOf("/", 8)` works, however I see that I assume that `b_context` is a root context, so there are potentially shorted sighted assumptions in my code. If the question was if `indexOf()` was worse than `lastIndexOf()` I could see `indexOf([magic number])` setting off style alarms.  Guess it depends on the final set of assumptions.  Hopefully I at least got OP unstuck :)